# angular-sortablejs is compatible with angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, sortables, angular-sortablejs

i was trying to use angular-sortables to sort the dragged(by ng-drag-drop library) list items but seems like nothing is happening by using it too.
**Can someone tell me if it is compatible with angular 5 or not ?**

*Below is my code :*

```
<div class="card-header card-inverse card-primary">Drop Anything here</div>
  <div class="card-block scroll-list" [sortablejs]="droppedHorizontalItems" [sortablejsOptions]="{ animation: 150 }">
    <li 
      [draggable]
      [dragClass]="'active'"
      [dragData]="item"
      [dragScope]="item.type"
      [dragEnabled]="dragEnabled"
      *ngFor="let item of droppedHorizontalItems;let in=index"
      class="horizontal list-group-item"
    >
      {{item.name}}
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know for ng-drag-drop library, but *ngFor Remove From Angular 5, *ngFor Deprecated in Angular 4.x use NgForOf Instead of *ngFor.

Answer (score 1):

[angular-sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs) works with angular 2, 4, 5 and will work with future versions.

Source: I'm the maintainer of the project. If you need further help feel free to ask at the github repo's issues page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the information from [angular-sortablejs github page](https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs):

> Angular >= 4.x (angular-sortablejs@2.x.x; sortablejs must be installed
>   separately)
>
> npm install --save sortablejs && npm install --save angular-sortablejs

So, I think that you shouldn't have any problem with it.

P.S. Sorry, but I didn't see your example. Maybe it'll be better to add plunker link.

Comment: this is not working , i tried the way given in the page

Answer (score 0):

angular-sortables doesn't work with any angular version >= 2.0.

Instead of that, you can use https://github.com/SortableJS/angular-sortablejs.